# Construct bridge by using N sections and find minimum cost

Tags: algorithm

> You have to construct a bridge in a city. Bridge consists of n
> sections (1 to n). There are m construction teams. The Ith team will
> work on the section from (li to ri) of the bridge. Bridge is said to
> be constructive if all sections from (1 to n) are worked on by at
> least one of the teams.
>
> The cost of building a section is number of teams that worked on it,
> So the cost of building the bridge is the sum of the cost of cost of
> building all the sections.
>
> Your task is to choose a subset of the teams such that bridge is
> completely constructed(i.e all the sections from (1 to n) is worked on
> by at least one of the team from this subset) and cost of building the
> bridge is the minimum possible. If it is not possible, print -1.
>
> Examples: `N=4 m=3; teams = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]`
>
> Approach :
>
> 1. The optimal way is to choose team 1 and team 3. 2) Sections 1 and 2
>    will be constructed by team 1 and sections 3 and 4 will be by team 3
> 2. so cost of constructing the bridge will be 4, as each section is
>    worked on exactly 1 team.
>
> Hence answer is 4.

Please provide the efficient approach for this problem.

Comment: It looks like this is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045387/how-to-cover-a-range-using-a-set-of-ranges-with-minimal-overlap).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the greedy algorithm - always the best place to start.

```
allocate all teams
IF not all sections covered
    output -1
    stop
mark all teams non-critical
flag_improved = true
WHILE( flag_improved == true )
   flag_improved = false
   find most expensive section 
   find most expensive non-critical team on most expensive section 
   IF team found that can be removed without leaving a section uncovered
       remove team
       flag_improved = true
   ELSE
       mark team critical
output cost - sum coverage of remaining teams
```

definitions:

- most expensive section is one with most teams allocated to it
- most expensive team is one that covers the most section

find most expensive non-critical team on most expensive section :

```
most_expense = 0
team
LOOP t over teams assigned to most expensive section
   IF team is critical
        continue
   IF team expense > most_expense
        most_expense = team expense
        team = t
```

Here is the main function of a C++ application implementing this algorithm

```
main()
{
    std::vector<cTeam> teams;
    int bridge_section_count;
    Input( bridge_section_count, teams);

    // allocate all teams
    for (int s = 0; s < bridge_section_count; s++)
        Bridge.insert(std::pair(s, std::vector<cTeam>(0)));
    for (auto &t : teams)
        for (int s = t.myRange.first; s <= t.myRange.second; s++)
        {
            Bridge[s].push_back(t);
        }

    // check every section has at least one team allocated
    if (!IsCovered())
    {
        std::cout << "-1\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // loop while improvements are being found
    bool flag_improved = true;
    while (flag_improved)
    {
        flag_improved = false;

        auto most_expensive_section = find_most_expensive_section();

        while (1)
        {
            // loop over teams allocated to most expensive section
            std::vector<cTeam>::iterator most_expensive_team;
            if (!find_most_expensive_non_critical_team(
                    most_expensive_team,
                    most_expensive_section))
            {
                break;
            }

            // check can team be removed without leaving section uncovered
            if (testRemoval(*most_expensive_team))
            {
                // remove team
                doRemoval(*most_expensive_team);
                flag_improved = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // this team is critical, it cannot be removed
                most_expensive_team->myCritical = true;
            }
        }
    }
    printResult();
}
```

The complete application code is at https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/ada6210a8517671abd45e882c97d526d

Comment: But in this approach you haven't talk about how to find minimum cost??

Comment: When the algorithm finishes you can calculate the cost very simply -sum the coverage of the allocated teams

Comment: Can you please provide me a solution ASAP. I am not getting this pseudo code.

Comment: Which is the first line of the psuedo code that you don't understand?

Comment: How to find this :- find most expensive non-critical team on most expensive section

Comment: You have to decide on a data structure.  I suggest a map, keyed by sections and storing a vector of teams allocated to that sector.  So, loop over the teams assigned to the most expensive section, storing the one that has the most sections.

Comment: I have expanded that line.  You will write code like this several times a day if you decide to become a professional coder.